# Who knows details about logger options?

Tags: logging, phalcon

somebody knows which logger options are available for Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File and what they do?

I did only find those two examples in the documentation:

- http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Logger_Adapter_File.html
- http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/logging.html#file-logger

Where option 'w' is used for creating directories & files. Therefore I would "guess" it will be used for fopen $mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It accepts `['mode' => '…']` and proxies it to the `fopen` function with some initial validation. You can [see for yourself here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/d5caf53f8f41669455905964ac5350ae546adc01/ext/logger/adapter/file.c#L95). By default it sets it to `ab`, I've no idea what `b` stands for, I can't see it in the [official docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Comment: b is to force binary mode - see fopen docs in "Note" section below mode explanation table.

Comment: tl;dr the first time ;)

Comment: great - 404 --noob